# Dynamics CRM paging limit for associated view differs per user

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have an entity 'A' that is associated with entity 'B'
when i select to view the associated view of 'B' on the page of 'A' the view contains all records "120 record" in the same page with a scroll bar, for my colleague with his user account, the view limits the number of records to be 50 per page so it is divided on 3 pages.

how to prevent that form happening and why is that happening to him although both user accounts have the same security roles, teams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer on [community website](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/147625)

> Yes you can change the View upto 250 records per page.
>   Click the Gear icon beside your Username on the Top right Corner and Open the "Options"  
>   Click General Tab
>   You will see the Option to change the  "records per Page". Scroll down to see various Options.

Comment: In addition to the link, pls share some context like how the content from the link resolved your problem. This will help others even if link is broken in future for any reason.